# Return true if all patterns exist in a given string in any order in Python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

I want to be able to find out if all of patterns in a given set exist in a string or not. The patterns could be a regex in itself
For example, if the input string is:

```
"Hello World"
```

Pattern set `("Hel.o Wo*","\*llo","l*d")` returns `true`

Pattern set `("Wor","el.","l*ed")` returns `false`

I know I can iterate through the pattern set and use re.search() but I was looking for one pattern search using `re` which should do the job. Something like:

`re.search("pattern1&pattern2&..","inputString")`

Comment: `if re.search(r"^(?=.*pattern1)(?=.*pattern2)(?=.*patternN)", inputString): print("yeah!")`

Comment: Awesome, that seemed to have worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) anchored at the start:

```
if re.search(r"^(?=.*pattern1)(?=.*pattern2)(?=.*patternN)", inputString):
    print("yeah!")
```

The [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will actually require the presence of all patterns regardless of their positions in the string.

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?=.*pattern1)`  - pattern1 after any 0+ chars other than line break chars *(if `re.DOTALL` is not used)
- `(?=.*pattern2)` - same with pattern2
- `(?=.*patternN)` - same with pattern3

Note the lookahead checks all are executed at the start of the string since lookaheads are zero-width assertions.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if those who downvote [working (=accepted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815447/return-true-if-all-patterns-exist-in-a-given-string-in-python/42861890#comment72829734_42815447), well-explained, not "here-you-are" answers could leave a note why they think this answer is not useful/helpful/poorly argumented. The point is that an incorrect answer has more upvotes than a correct answer, and this is baffling people who need the right solution to check if all the patterns match a single string in any order.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple matter of lining up the Boolean expressions you want, and slapping the *all** operator on the list:

```
text = "Hello World"
pattern = ("Hel","llo","ld")
all([str in text for str in pattern])
```

The list evaluates to **True** and **False** values; **all** does a logical **and** on the entire set; the **or** version is the **any** operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
>>> str_in = "Hello World"
>>> pattern = ("Hel","llo","ld")
>>> all([True if p in str_in else False for p in pattern])
True
>>> pattern = ("Wor","el","led")
>>> all([True if p in str_in else False for p in pattern])
False
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, a recursive solution would look like:

```
def search(string, patterns):
    found = len(re.findall(patterns[0], string)) > 0

    if len(patterns) == 1:
        return found
    return found and search(string, patterns[1::])
```